# Find a nonempty proper subset, $A$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Suppose $(X,d)=(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, L^\infty)$

Find a nonempty proper subset, $A$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with the following characteristics:

- The set $A$ is infinite.
- The complement of the set $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus A$ is infinite.
- The set $A$ is open.

Note that $L^{\infty}$ means $d((x,y),(x’,y’))=max(|x-x’|,|y-y’|)$.

Let $C=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}$, and $A=C^c=\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z})$.

To show that $A$ and $C$ are infinite, define $f_A: \mathbb{N} \to A$ by $n \mapsto (n,\frac{1}{2})$, and $f_C: \mathbb{N} \to C$ by $n \mapsto (n,1)$.

Suppose $f_A(a)=f_A(b)$. Then $(a,\frac{1}{2})=(b,\frac{1}{2}) \iff a=b$. Thus $f_A$ is an injection.

Suppose $f_C(a)=f_C(b)$. Then $(a,1)=(b,1) \iff a=b$. Thus $f_C$ is an injection.

Therefore, $A$ and $C$ are infinite.

To prove that $A$ is open, let $a \in A$. Then $a=(a_1,a_2)$, where $a_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$. Choose $\varepsilon:=\min(a_2-\lfloor a_2\rfloor, 1+\lfloor a_2\rfloor-a_2)$, so that $y \in B_{\varepsilon}(a) \iff d((y_1,y_2),(a_1,a_2))=max(|y_1-a_1|,|y_2-a_2|)<min(a_2-\lfloor a_2\rfloor, 1+\lfloor a_2\rfloor-a_2)$.

As $y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, y=(y_1,y_2)$ with $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. So $B_{\varepsilon}(a) \subseteq A \iff y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $\varepsilon$ is either $a_2-\lfloor a_2\rfloor$ or $1+\lfloor a_2\rfloor-a_2$, consider the following two cases:

Case 1: If $\varepsilon=a_2-\lfloor a_2\rfloor$, then $|y_2-a_2|<a_2-\lfloor a_2\rfloor$. Now, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $x-\lfloor x \rfloor \in [0,1)$. But $a_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, so $a_2-\lfloor a_2 \rfloor \in (0,1)$. Thus $|y_2-a_2|=0 \iff y_2=a_2 \iff y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Case 2: If $\varepsilon=1+\lfloor a_2\rfloor-a_2$, then $|y_2-a_2|<1+\lfloor a_2\rfloor-a_2<a_2-\lfloor a_2 \rfloor \Rightarrow |y_2-a_2|<a_2-\lfloor a_2 \rfloor$. Thus $|y_2-a_2|=0 \iff y_2=a_2 \iff y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

In either case, $y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus $\forall y \in B_{\varepsilon}(a), y \in A$, and hence $\forall a \in A, \exists \varepsilon>0 \ni B_{\varepsilon}(a) \subseteq A$. Therefore, $A$ is open.

Is my reasoning here correct?

Comment: $C$ is closed as the product of the closed sets $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$. It's clearly infinite as it contains a copy of $\Bbb R$. So the complement is open and infinite (it also contains a copy of $\Bbb R$).

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what the distance $d=L^{\infty}$ means on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net it means $d((x,y),(x’,y’))=max(|x-x’|,|y-y’|)$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma would you please clarify why the product of closed sets is closed. Also, what do you mean by “copy of $\mathbb{R}$”?

Comment: in the product topology (same as box for finite products, nice and simple),  the open sets are the cross product of open sets in the first component and open in the second.   Equivalently, the closed sets are thus the product of closed sets in the first and closed in the second.  (For the infinite product topology, you need all but a finite number of the components to be the whole space for open sets/ the empty set for closed sets)

Comment: The metric induces the product topology on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ and in that topology products of closed sets are closed. And I call a set like $\Bbb R \times \{0\}$ a copy of $\Bbb R$.